# How to create several 3D plots with plt.addplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I had expect such code to work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,projection='3d')
```

but it fails telling me no parameter named projection.
I wonder whether I can create several 3D plots with addplots

Comment: `plt.addplots` does not exist.

Comment: Sorry, it is plt.subplots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `projection` is an argument of the Axes creator

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
```